# Good practice : compare a value with a boolean?

Tags: if-statement, boolean, code-readability

Most of the time, I prefer to write this :

```
if(isWelcome() == true){}
if(isWelcome() == false){}
```

instead of this

```
if(isWelcome()){}
if(!isWelcome()){}
```

Because I feel that it is easier to read (but I do understand that it doesn't make sense).

I would like to know if there is a common agreement about this practice. What most developer do? And I'm wondering if the compiler is doing the extra comparaison, or if it understand that it is useless.

Comment: I ask the question for a general case. It could be Java, C#, etc.

Comment: This question is somehow subjective and may be better on Programmer.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readability is important, and adding words does not always improve readability.  While this

```
if(isWelcome() == false){}
```

may be more readable than this

```
if(!isWelcome()){}
```

for someone who is not familiar with what ! does, this

```
if(isWelcome()){}
```

is actually more readable than this

```
if(isWelcome() == true){}
```

because now you've introduced "noise words" that are of no informational value, and add to the area your eyes need to scan to understand what's going on.  You should strive for minimal code that fully conveys the programmer's intent.

To actually answer your question, I will say that most programmers would use the shorter version.  Inexperienced programmers tend to use the "verbose" version.

Comment: I agree for the "true" form. But for the false form, is it only me or the "!" character is easy to miss, even if we are familiar with it?

Comment: Yes, because there is no use of whitespace in the example you provided. If you add a space between the if and the condition, it gets a little more noticeable. You can even pad the inner expression with a space on both sides, now you can't miss the !, and you've kept your code minimal while improving readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a tool like Resharper you get a hint that it is redundant to use isWelcome() == true.
The compiler can choose to optimize the comparison so I wouldn't worry too much about it.